# Apply high quality texture to ARKit 4 mesh

Tags: arkit, texture-mapping, lidar

I have run the samples of ARKit4 with iPhone12. The dense point clouds are great, the mesh ... not too much. It's a low poly mesh (sort of). But it can still be made to look pretty if We could apply High quality texture on it.

If that train of thought is correct, can someone please guide me how to go about it? Any pointers would help.

Previously (pre-Lidar), we would fuse Depth data into a voxels and then do a marching cube. But with these points clouds, what's the way forward? or with the mesh output, whichever is the correct path to take, and what should I be reading on.